Sample Size Calculation for Experiment Two Independent Groups with Binary Outcome With Unequal Number of Participants but Equal Number of Outcomes
I am trying to calculate the sample size needed for an experiment with two independent study groups with a dichotomous/binary outcome. The outcome consists of making a selection. Group 1 has three times as many participants as group 2; however, participants in group 2 make three times as many selections. This results in the total number of selections (the dichotomous / binary outcome) in group 1 being the same as the total number of selections in group 2. To calculate the sample size needed, would I determine the enrollment ratio based on the number of participants per group or the number of selections (again, the dichotomous / binary outcome) made per group?

A potential problem I see, well before sample size, is if the same subjects in group 2 make 3 times as many selections, then these selections may no longer be independent. Can you clarify how/why the individual selections (a single selection) would be independent? If not, you would have bigger problems than figuring out a sample size...

Thank you for your comment @jginestet ! The selections in group 2 will not be independent. I plan on run an ordinary least squares regression model with standard errors clustered by respondent to address this.
